# Convert native box to geometry

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have an old table that contains bounding boxes of lat long coordinates in a "box" type.
How do I convert them to PostGIS geometry ?

I tried using `ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(se.bound_box::box2d::geometry, 4326), 4326)` but it says I can't cast box to box2d or to geometry.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 9):

If the boxes are already in WGS84 datum, then the following should work

```
SELECT box2d(se.bound_box)::geometry
```